Linear models in statistics (Rencher), Theorem 7.9.c
In multiple regression context (under the general assumption we know), $X=(X_1,X_2)$ and $\beta^\prime=(\beta_1^\prime,\beta_2^\prime)$. Let $\hat{\beta_1^*}=(X_1^\prime X_1)^{-1}X_1^\prime y$ be the estimator from the reduced model.
According to Linear models in Statistics (Rencher), $cov(\hat{\beta_1})-cov(\hat{\beta_1^*})=\sigma^2 AB^{-1}A^\prime$, which is a positive definite matrix, where $A=(X_1^\prime X_1)^{-1}X_1^\prime X_2$ and $B=X_2^\prime X_2-X_2^\prime X_1 A$.
Here, I have a question.
Why is $AB^{-1}A^\prime$ a positive definite matrix?
I checked the contents about positive definite matrix in Chapter 2, but I cannot find the reason.

For clarity to people who have not read this book, the author uses $A'$ to denote the transpose $A^T$. And also the book states that the $X$ matrix has full rank (linearly independent columns).

First, note that $B$ is positive definite (reason below). That implies that $B^{-1}$ is positive definite, which in turn can be used to show that $A B^{-1} A'$ is positive definite.
B is positive definite: Expand the $A$ term in the expression of $B$ to get
$$ B = X_2' X_2 - X_2' X_1 (X_1' X_1)^{-1} X_1' X_2 = X_2' (I - X_1(X_1' X_1)^{-1} X_1') X_2 = X_2' H X_2 = X_2' H' H X_2 = (H X_2)' (H X_2)$$
where we use $H$ to denote $(I - X_1(X_1' X_1)^{-1} X_1')$, and also used the fact that $H$ is symmetric and idempotent.
Now suppose $v$ is a vector such that $v' Bv = 0$.
Then $$ v' Bv  = v' (H X_2)' (H X_2) v = \lVert H X_2 v \rVert = 0 $$
and so $v \in ker(H X_2)$. If we can show that $ker(H X_2) = \{ 0 \}$, then we are done.
So we need to show that $ker(H X_2) = \{ 0 \}$. From it's definition, $H$ is a projection onto the complement of the column space of $X$, denoted $col(X)$. (If this is not clear to you, you can look up the hat matrix and it's properties.) That means that $ker(H) = col(X)$. But because by assumption the matrix $X = \begin{pmatrix} X_1 & X_2 \end{pmatrix}$ is full rank, the matrices $X_1$ and $X_2$ must have linearly independent columns, and hence $col(X_2) \cap ker(H) = col(X_2) \cap col(X_1) = \{0\}$. From this, and the fact that $X_2$ is injective, you can use some linear algebra to reason that $ker(H X_2) = \{ 0 \}$.
